# Cannot set graphviz output to pdf

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, graphviz, dot

I'm trying to use Graphviz fo the decision tree classifier, the code is here.

I expect the output of a diagram but the actual output is this message:

```
warning, language pdf not recognized, use one of:
 dot canon plain plain-ext
dot: option -O unrecognized
warning, language svg not recognized, use one of:
 dot canon plain plain-ext
```

Any help is appreciated

```py
import graphviz 
dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(dtc, out_file=None)
graph = graphviz.Source(dot_data) 
graph.render("data")
graph
```

Comment: Did you download the Graphviz as well other than installing it with pip install ?

Comment: yes I did install Graphviz